# Unpack list of dictionary into separate columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list, unpack

Let's assume I have data which is structured like such:

```
{ 
    "_id" : 245, 
    "connId" : "3r34b32", 
    "roomList" : [
        {
            "reportId" : 29, 
            "siteId" : 1
        }]
}
```

How do I go about getting the keys from the dictionary within the list, along with the value in order for it to have this expected output below.

Expected Output:

```
ID,connID,reportId,siteId

245,3r34b32,29,1
```

I'm using `json_normalize` but this does not work with lists, so I need to add an extra bit of code which can unpack the list that contains a dictionary.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Check `pd.json_normalize(dct, 'roomList', ['_id', 'connId'])`

Comment: Is there an alternative rather than explicitly specifying the column name? As the code needs to be written in a way for it to be automated

Comment: Which column are you referring to?

Comment: roomList, however, it needs to be done in a way which the column name doesn't need to be specified so it will be dynamic

Comment: Is that guaranteed always one list of records present per data dictionary? So for example in this case only one list of records is associated with key `roomList` in the data dictionary.

Comment: it's not always guaranteed, it can be one list or more than one. So i'm going for a dynamic approach to make it more efficient.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228756/discussion-between-user3396351-and-shubham-sharma).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a nested record. You can handle them separately with `record_path` and them concatenate them with `pd.concat()`

```
root = pd.json_normalize(d).drop('roomList',1)
nested = pd.json_normalize(d, record_path='roomList')
output = pd.concat([root, nested],axis=1)
print(output)
```

```
   _id   connId  reportId  siteId
0  245  3r34b32        29       1
```

---

#### Method without explicit column names

If you don't want to specify a column name explicitly you can do the following. This checks which of the columns after normalization are nested, separately normalizes them and concatenates all of them. I have added another nested JSON for sake of example -

```
root = pd.json_normalize(d)
nested_cols = [i for i in root.columns if isinstance(root[i][0], list)]

l = [root.drop(nested_cols,1),]
for i in nested_cols:
    l.append(pd.json_normalize(d, record_path=i))

output = pd.concat(l, axis=1)
print(output)
```

```
   _id   connId  reportId  siteId  reportId2  siteId2
0  245  3r34b32        29       1         39        5
```

**NOTE:** If some of your nested records have same names, you many want to use some prefix while normalizing them. [Check this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) for more details.

Comment: glad to help anytime.

Comment: @AkshaySehgal Very clever idea of checking the type of the first entry in all columns... In the list comprehension you could use a more preferred way  of type checking that is`isinstance(root[i][0], list)` instead of  `type(root[i][0])==list` :)

Comment: great input, i was wondering whether i should make that change, but i just got too lazy to do it :)